# Get new value after javascript update

Tags: javascript

I use some javascript to update a text value. It's original value is "hello world"

```
document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = myprice;
```

Later I try to access to updated value (i.e the one I can see on the screen, and what was updated by javascript)

```
var my2price = document.getElementById("cost").innerText;
```

The thing is, it says "hello world" even though I have since updated it with javascript. How can I grab the current value, even if it was previously updated by javascript from it's original load state?

Comment: You're not showing enough code for a definitive answer. Are you using a textbox? because then you're not looking for `innerText`, you're looking for `value`

Comment: Hello @zfrisch . It's the text inside a span - does that make a difference in my case?

Comment: Please add an example fiddle or code block

Comment: Please, share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `The thing is, it says "hello world"` - how? except if myprice is `hello world` - you've assumed we can see the rest of your code

Comment: From what you've explained it should be working. You would need to show us your exact code. It sounds like it's probably a scoping issue.

Comment: @Jimmy if you use asynchronous function(like ajax) to update text,  you have to access updated element in callback/resolved promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error somewhere, but not in the lines you write. Try this:

```
document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "Testing"
var output = document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML;
alert(output); // alerts Testing
```

So you need to post more code to get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the last bad answer...
So let's suppose that you have:

```
<span id="cost"> some text </span>
```

And you can make...

```
var text = document.getElementById("cost");

text.innerHTML = "another text";
```

then you can test...

```
console.log(text.innerHTML); //That's it ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("cost").innerText = myprice;
var myPrice2 = document.getElementById("cost").innerText;
console.log(myPrice2);
```

and check your browser console.